# How can I make the view mode of folders on a usb drive the same on different computers?

Tags: windows, usb-storage, desktop-customization, files-folders

For example, the drive letter of a usb drive is H:\. I set the view mode of a folder on this drive to list. When I change the drive letter, the view mode of this folder will not be list anymore. I edit desktop.ini, but it doesn't work. I guess the information is stored in system partition instead of the folder itself, and based on the drive letter. How can I make the view mode of folders on a usb drive the same on different computers? This is a usb drive, so it will be used on different computers, and even if on the same computer, the drive letter could change. I don't want to set the view mode of every folder every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has NOTHING to do with the file system or with usb-storage.  It is too bad that those pesky desktop.ini files can't be edited to do this but that isn't one of the properties that they control.  "Back in the days" between Windows 98 and Windows 2000, you could do all kinds of nifty things (probably even this) using "web view" (or some such name) but those features were axed due to security concerns.

***Windows uses the windows registry to save the preferred state of particular folders.***

These keys are often referred to as "ShellBags" because that is what one of the authors of Explorer.exe named the root key plus the first key right under it.  Technically.. they are "Shell\Bags".  I have read that they appeared in the XP days but I seem to remember something very similar (if not this) dating all of the way back to Windows 95.

Edit:  @KeithMiller has been kind enough to remind me that these keys were probably "ShellNoRoam" pre-XP.  Although I once knew this.. there is just not enough space in the cranium to keep more worthless knowledge than I am already carrying.

Windows uses these registry keys to save folder information:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell

***You are probably not going to be successful with your current adventure I am sorry to say.  Explore them for yourself and you will see what I mean.  I would love to be proven wrong! :)***

NirSoft makes a [nifty free tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_bags_view.html) for browsing the keys if you want to get fancy.

One last interesting tidbit regarding these keys.  They leave a forensic trail behind that can tell the trained eye where you have been in your file system while using the explorer.  There has been some controversy behind this but most people either don't know or don't care (I myself don't care).

[This article](https://www.magnetforensics.com/blog/forensic-analysis-of-windows-shellbags/) is very well written and not only describes how the mechanism works, but describes the "controversy" I describe above.

Someone else here might have a clever way to deal with this but I myself have never heard of one.  I have to assume that any solution will be shoddy at best.

Comment: I think `ShellNoRoam` was last seen on XP. The current location of the `BagMRU` and `Bags` keys that hold the view settings of local folders is `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`. `HHKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell` still holds the view settings for the Desktop and network folders.

Comment: Thank you guys. Seems like there is no solution for this. Bad system design.

Comment: Thats right @KeithMiller!  "ShellNoRoam".. not seen that in a long time.